# Where can I find Pandoc's `man` page, and how do I install it?

Tags: pandoc, haskell-stack, manpage

I installed a Haskell program on my Mac with the command `stack install pandoc`, and now I'd like to read about it. When I run `man pandoc`, I get the message *No manual entry for pandoc*. `which pandoc` returns `~/.local/bin/pandoc`.

From running `man man`, I understand that `man` tries to find a suitable `man` file by "a sophisticated method of finding manual page files, based on the invocation options and environment variables," but are there standards for how such a file should be delivered, and where you should put it once you have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install pandoc
```

that also installs a man page and (unlike stack) doesn't build from source.

For further options, see [Installing Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: This worked for me: it installs the man page in a place `man` can find it, so I'll mark it as the answer. I'm not sure in general when I should use `stack` vs `brew` for Haskell tools like this, though. Thanks!

Comment: stack you only need if it's not on brew or you are developing haskell code yourself...

Comment: In this case I was working on the tutorials to write filters myself, so I was developing haskell code, just not that's properly part of Pandoc . I guess that's what got me hung up. Thanks!